# Convert Xml to php string

Tags: php, xml

I am using below code for converting xml response to php string but I am getting below error

> "Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found....."
>   "Warning: simplexml_load_string(): example.com...."
>   "Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^ in /home/example/public_html/example.php on line 9"

```
<?php
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>';
$url= "example.com";
$xml = simplexml_load_string($url);
echo $xml->status;
?>
```

Comment: `$url` is not valid xml (perhaps we should say 'example.php' is not valid XML) - so no surprise at the error

Comment: `simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents($url));` should help... Assuming this is a standard website and `allow_url_fopen` is `on` in your `php.ini`

Comment: did you mean `simplexml_load_file($url)` ? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `simplexml_load_string` expects an XML string to be passed as parameter, which is not the case of your code: the content of `$url` variable is not a valid XML string, thus, you get those errors.

You may want to load the `$url` as a file instead. Example:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
```

Final code:

```
<?php
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>';
$url ="example.com";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
echo $xml->status;
```